# How to preserve a value in a case statement in verilog

Tags: case, verilog, hdl, synthesis

When designing finite state machines in verilog, I find myself writing code like this a lot to preserve a value in a particular state.

```
always@(state, a, b) begin
  case(state) begin
    S1: a = b;
    S2: a = a; // preserve a;
  endcase
end
```

This is necessary because if I don’t specify a value for each register in the sensitivity list, the compiler will infer a latch. To me this feels like a code smell, but I’m not experienced enough to know for sure. Is this the best way to preserve a value in verilog?

Answer (score 1):

Preserve state means to create a latch, which is a device that do exactly that.

`a=a` is a *null* statement and you should not use it at all.

Do not use sensetivity lists in the always block, they are error prone, use @* instead.

And, for latches, you should use non-blocking assignments.

Your latch case statement should look like the following:

```
always@(*) begin
  case(state) begin
    S1: a <= b;
    S2: // do nothing about 'a', a will not change.
  endcase
end
```

in general the FSM scheme use in industry uses clocks and looks like the following:

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
  case(state) begin
    S1: begin
          next_state <= S2;
          a <= b;
        end
    S2: // do nothing about 'a', a will not change.
    ....
  endcase
end
assign state = next_state;
```